# WebInspect Issue while running REST API Scans

Tags: json, api, rest, fortify, web-inspector

I am getting this error message while running REST API Scans on WebInspect tool: "Please verify a connection, we cannot capture any sessions". Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this error. Two of the most common would be our inability to parse the API definition file or access issues connecting to the site. The access issue could either be authentication or network related.
My recommendation would be opening a ticket with Fortify support (https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/support/contact-support) as there are some follow-up questions:

- What API type are you scanning?
- Is this a Postman based scan? If so, can it be run my Newman?
- How is the scan configured?
- Do you have any problems executing WiSwag from cli?
- What are you seeing in the scan logs?